# PHP Nested array loop undefined levels

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multi-dimension nested array. The example below is how the array is nested. However, the amount of levels nested can vary. I need to dynamically loop through them. I would like to do this without using json_encode. Any ideas how I can achieve this?

```
$array = array(
    'brands' => array(
        'codes' => array('b' => "Apple", 'c' => 21, 'd' => 18),
        'items' => array('b' => "Google", 'c' => 22, 'd' => 19),
        'stock' => array('b' => "Samsung", 'c' => 23, 'd' => 20)
    )
);
```

*** UPDATE ***

I would like the output to look like a json layout but without using json_encode. Should end up looking like the example below. But the levels of the nest can vary:

```
"brands":{
      "codes":{
         "b":"Apple",
         "c":"21",
         "d":"18"
      },
      "items":{
         "b":"Google",
         "c":"22",
         "d":"19"
      },
      "stock":{
         "b":"Samsung",
         "c":"23",
         "d":"20"
      },
}
```

Comment: loop through them how, why is the number of levels undetermined?

Comment: Perhaps you could use [array_walk_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using a recursive function call. E.g.

```
function walk_array($array) {
  foreach($array as $idx => $val) {
    if(is_array($val)) {
      walk_array($val);
    } else {
      /* found a value, do something with it */
      echo $idx . " = " . $val . "<br>";
    }
  }
}

walk_array($array);
```

The idea is to iterate the array in a function `walk_array`, and check if the current array element is again an array. If that is the case start over iterating the array by calling `walk_array` with the found array. With this technique there is no limit how deep the array may be nested.

Comment: Sorry, I just realised I missed out a complete piece of information. I want to display the data almost like json but without using json_encode. I've updated my question to show how I would like the output to look. How can I use the above example for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is recursion

checkout how I solve your problem by printing the key and value for each item

```
$array = array(
    'brands' => array(
        'codes' => array('b' => "Apple", 'c' => 21, 'd' => 18),
        'items' => array('b' => "Google", 'c' => 22, 'd' => 19),
        'stock' => array('b' => "Samsung", 'c' => 23, 'd' => 20)
    )
);

printArray($array);


function printArray($array){

    $keys = array_keys($array);
    foreach($keys as $key){
        $value = $array[$key];
        if(is_array($value)){
            printArray($value);
        }else{
            echo $key . " " . $value . "<br/>";
        }
    }
}
```